# Webpage Memory Increasing drastically

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, flot

I have an EmberJs application which uses FlotJS to render charts. In one particular chart, where we draw 50+ bars in a chart, the memory of the web page increases drastically and its not reducing even after moving to other pages. When that chart is rendered some 5+ times the web page crashes. Chrome Task Manager shows following details,

Before rendering chart,
Memory - 259MB
GPU Memory - 63.7MB
Javascript Memory - 22,982K(12,755K live)

After rendering chart,
Memory - 396MB
GPU Memory - 58.2MB
Javascript Memory - 46,233K(29,059K live)

When plot function of FlotJS is commented, there is <1MB increase in the Memory utilisation.

What could be the possible reason?? The Memory value shown by Chrome Task Manager comprises of what?? Is FlotJS introducing any memory leak??

Comment: How can you make sure you only generating 50+ bars but not repeat generating?

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: @jhyap not getting your question.. what repeat generating??

Comment: Can you show us how you draw the chart?  Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?  I've used flot extensively (redrawing charts with 40+ line series dozens of times) and have not encountered memory issues (in fact it's speed and low memory foot print is one of the reasons I use it).

Comment: @Mark Since i faced some problem with jsFiddle, i have hosted it on google drive.  Here is the link. Clcik on the button 'click' more than 2 times and see the memory utilization of the page. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzfiykS3PhMWUzA5NmN6OVV5QzQ/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I can kinda reproduce the memory usage.  I had to go to extremes though and essentially do this:

```
while(true)
{
    $('.flot').empty();
    $.plot(".flot", [JSON.parse(data)] );
}
```

This caused thousands upon thousands of redraws and chewed up memory.

Emptying the div and re-initing the chart is not the proper way to redraw, however.  You [should be using](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods) a combination of `setData`, `setupGrid` and `draw`.  Doing this:

```
var splot = null;
while(true)
{
    if (splot == null)
    {
        splot = $.plot(".flot", [JSON.parse(data)] );
    }
    else
    {
        splot.setData([JSON.parse(data)]);
        splot.draw();
    }       
}
```

My memory usage was flat.

Also, your sample code doesn't show how you are using emberJS.  I'm not very familiar with it, but I'd check very carefully that in it's data-binding glory it's not forcing the chart to redraw too frequently.